# Small Postgres Table vs Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Im working on a personal project where I have a database of movie titles where each title has an array of genre_id's which are integers that correspond to genre names. There are 20 or less possible genres and i don't foresee having to add any in the future. I normally would just make the database table with "ID" and "Name" and reference that in my queries.

But in a personal project situation like this with such a small set I'm wondering if there is any reason not to just have a JS object which i just substitute genreName[genre_ID] wherever i return the genres, rather than going through the "trouble" (and i say that with air quotes because I'm obviously being lazy) to create a Postgres table for genres and change out the ID's for names in my database query.

I'm just wondering if one method would have any serious drawbacks over the other? I see no time or space complexity issues with this, Is it just separation of concerns/convention?

Comment: Create the genres table; you'll be glad you did.

Comment: You can also use [enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) . Care that it should be used with mostly static lookup data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tradeoff here is pay-me-now versus pay-me-later.

If you spend the extra few minutes to create `movie`, `genre`, the many-to-many `movie_genre` join table, and the FK constraints, you will not find yourself delving into unnesting arrays for a new report you would like to see or scratching your head over how a bogus `genre_id` somehow made it into your `movie` table.

There are a number of PITA concerns over how to populate your tables.  I hear them and understand them, but there are good practices to help deal with them, and as I said up front, it's pay-me-now or pay-me-later.  There is no shortage of NoSQL dumpster fires out there that will cost a fortune in time and money to fix because somebody took a shortcut.

Please let me know if you have any questions on this, and I will be happy to discuss it with you here.

Answer (score -1):

One of the drawback of not using a table in your database is that you cannot have foreign keys referencing it, so your movie data is not constrained to have valid genres.

Comment: That's not the only reason.  There are many others.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, it's just the first I thought of, and it alone seemed to be reason enough to use a table. If you can name others, please put an answer :-)